# Only have 100, 200,300 and 500 quantity

Tags: quantity

I'm new in Magento - I'm more use to work with wordpress but Here i am !

I'm having few problems with an option I would like to setup:

When the user goes to product detail, I would like him to be able only to select 100 - 200 - 300 and 500 quantity of the product.

Does anybody know how to achieve this ? I've been exploring around and see what I need to use bundles, However, I don;t manage to make this setup correctly !!

Anybody which is use to do that, I would love any help :)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: thank you, I already tried that and dint manage to make this work :/

Comment: What have you tried, what do you expect, what happens and what is the problem? Please edit your question to include these infos.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the result you're asking for, but one option is to instead describe your item (in the title) as "quantity of 100"?  If your SKUs are frequently for these lot-orders then you might add a custom attribute to use in your product descriptions and blocks.